# Overriding filters from classes in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying override a function from class **WC_Admin_Post_Types** and tried something like this:

plugins/customization/wc_admin_post_types_new.php

```
class WC_Admin_Post_Types_new {
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'views_edit-product', array( $this, 'product_sorting_link_new' ) );
    }
    public function product_sorting_link_new( $views ) {
        global $post_type, $wp_query;

        if ( ! current_user_can('edit_others_pages') ) {
            return $views;
        }

        $class            = ( isset( $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) && $wp_query->query['orderby'] == 'menu_order title' ) ? 'current' : '';
        $query_string     = remove_query_arg(array( 'orderby', 'order' ));
        $query_string     = add_query_arg( 'orderby', urlencode('menu_order title'), $query_string );
        $query_string     = add_query_arg( 'order', urlencode('ASC'), $query_string );
        $views['byorder'] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $query_string ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '">' . __( 'Sort Courses', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';

        return $views;
    }
}
new WC_Admin_Post_Types_new();
```

Original class looks like this

plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-post-types.php

```
class WC_Admin_Post_Types {
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'views_edit-product', array( $this, 'product_sorting_link' ) );
    }
    public function product_sorting_link( $views ) {
        global $post_type, $wp_query;

        if ( ! current_user_can('edit_others_pages') ) {
            return $views;
        }

        $class            = ( isset( $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) && $wp_query->query['orderby'] == 'menu_order title' ) ? 'current' : '';
        $query_string     = remove_query_arg(array( 'orderby', 'order' ));
        $query_string     = add_query_arg( 'orderby', urlencode('menu_order title'), $query_string );
        $query_string     = add_query_arg( 'order', urlencode('ASC'), $query_string );
        $views['byorder'] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $query_string ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '">' . __( 'Sort Products', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';

        return $views;
    }
}
new WC_Admin_Post_Types();
```

I am trying to change

```
$views['byorder'] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $query_string ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '">' . __( 'Sort Products', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
```

with

```
$views['byorder'] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $query_string ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '">' . __( 'Sort Courses', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
```

Tried adding

```
remove_filter( 'views_edit-product', array( 'WC_Admin_Post_Types', 'product_sorting_link_new' ) );
```

in the `__construct` and outside the class, but always returned false.

So how can I remove this filter and replace `Sort Products` with `Sort Courses` without editing or without using .pot. Need to know because there will be more altering on different classes from woocommerce.

Comment: Does anyone one though how to use remove_action / remove_filter. I am not in a problem that only overriding doesn't work and I need to remove also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I have written a little function:

```
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Sort Products' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Sort Courses', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 )
```

- You can see the docs here for [remove filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter#Example)
- And you can see the dcos here for [remove action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action#Example)

However I find this method to be quite clean.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Though this would be a fix for only one text, actually the switch will be activated only when you click desired zone, but if you also want to change the admin menu won't work with another case. And seams to be replacing first instance of a text not all. Though very good solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Found a temporary fix, but still not able to do it by the book like remove the filter or action. I added this function outside the class, before the class and it worked overriding.

```
function mfields_test_remove_actions() {
    var_dump(remove_filter( 'views_edit-product', array( 'WC_Admin_Post_Types', 'product_sorting_link_new' ) )); // still returnes false but add filter is overriding it.
    add_filter( 'views_edit-product', array( 'WC_Admin_Post_Types_new', 'product_sorting_link_new' ) );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'mfields_test_remove_actions' );
```